# Return "real" parsed javascript code from URL

Tags: php

I need to load from remote (or local) websites, the "real" result of the web, include parsed javascript (like JSON, ajax request, etc).

Im try some methods, include call a website using epiphany-browser under console, but i dont find the command to return the result to file or stream (for using with PHP "system" command).

How i can get the parsed code of website, include the result of JS scripts, to PHP? (under Debian Server)

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Define "parsed" in this context. Do you mean you wish to execute the Javascript and return the rendered output?

Comment: Exactly, i need the executed javascript included

Comment: That is what web browsers do. You can certainly write your own web browser, I suppose, but it seems to me that you would be more productive if you simply use one of the many available browsers and add plugins or Greasemonkey-type scripts as needed to automate your tasks.

Comment: yes, write a browser is not factible at this time :)
its possible to get the parsed page of a browser by console command? I read examples but use lynx and this dont parse javascript, epyphany yes, but i dont know if i can get the browser result as return.